# DEFAULT ERROR CALL BACK on JayData

Tags: javascript, cordova, jaydata

When I add or save some data on using JayData and SQL Lite Provider (in phone gap).  I get the follwing error:

DefaultError: DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK!

Exception
data: Arguments[1]
0: SQLError
code: 0
message: "the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false"
**proto**: SQLError
......
length: 1
**proto**: Object
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK!"
name: "DefaultError"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
**proto**: Object
 jaydata.min.js:53
Guard.raise jaydata.min.js:53
Uncaught DefaultError: DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK!

However the record is added/updated ok.  No idea what the problem could be... any ideas?

The code is:

```
//Entities:
var Task = $data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Task", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true },
    TaskType: { type: String, required: false },
    StatusId: { type: "int", required: false },
    DateScheduled:  { type: Date, required: false },
    TimeSlot:  { type: String, required: false },
    LastUpdated:  { type: Date,required: false },
    TaskName:  { type: String, required: false },    
    SpecialInstructions:  { type: String},
    PropertyAddress:  { type: String, required: false },
    PropertyPostCode:  { type: String, required: false },
    PropertyType:  { type: String, required: false },
    NumberOfBedrooms:  { type: "int", required: false },
    HasGarage:  { type: Boolean, required: false },
    HasOutHouse:  { type: Boolean, required: false },
    IsReadyForReportGeneration: {type: Boolean},
    TaskStatus: {type: String},
    DateOfTaskDisplayName: {type: String}
});

//inside a look etc:

taskToUpdate.TaskType = task.TaskType;
                        taskToUpdate.StatusId = task.TaskStatusId;
                        taskToUpdate.TaskStatus = task.TaskStatus;
                        taskToUpdate.DateScheduled = task.Date;
                        taskToUpdate.TimeSlot = task.Time;
                        taskToUpdate.LastUpdated = new Date();
                        taskToUpdate.TaskName = "Job " + task.TaskId + " " + task.TaskType + " @" + task.AddressOfTask + ", " + task.PropertyPostCode;
                        taskToUpdate.SpecialInstructions = specialInstructions;
                        taskToUpdate.PropertyAddress = task.AddressOfTask;
                        taskToUpdate.PropertyPostCode = task.PropertyPostCode;
                        taskToUpdate.PropertyType = task.PropertyType;
                        taskToUpdate.NumberOfBedrooms = task.NumberOfBedrooms;
                        taskToUpdate.HasGarage = task.HasGarage;
                        taskToUpdate.HasOutHouse = task.HasOutHouse;
                        taskToUpdate.DateOfTaskDisplayName = task.DateOfTaskDisplayName,
                        taskToUpdate.IsReadyForReportGeneration = task.ReportReady;

                        if (result.length == 0) {
                            $org.context.Task.add(taskToUpdate);
                        }

                        rowsProcessed++;

                        if (rowsProcessed == rowsToProcess) {
                            $org.context.saveChanges({
                                success: function(db) {
                                    viewModel.messages.push({message:"Tasks saved to local device."});
                                    showNotificationInfo("Tasks saved to local device.");
                                    hideLoader();
                                }, error: function(err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    viewModel.messages.push({message:"Errors saving tasks: " + err});
                                    showNotificationError("Errors saving tasks: " + err);   
                                    hideLoader();
                                }
                            });  
                        }
```

Comment: how do you instantiate taskToUpdate ?

Comment: With attachOrGet...funny thing, it used to work fine until I changed some table definition.. I tried using the dropAllTables option too to check if it was some issue with model change..

Comment: adding computed=true to the definition of the Id would help to make sure you have unique values. does this change the behavior?

Comment: The id isn't computed... the data actually comes from a server (the tasks are locally stored / synched) so the ID's are always unique (the server Id is an identity column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIght It turned out I was calling a method --logInfo(message)  that was calling context.savechanges() too.

By calling this with the log create message, it was causing the error... however all the data was saved ok so I'm still a little unsure what was really going on...

I've now made sure that savechanges() is only called after all work is done and only called once...

Thanks for helping out people ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to occur because you don't have any Id set in case you add the new record.
The fix for this is easy:

```
if (result.length == 0) {
  taskToUpdate.Id = task.Id;
  $org.context.Task.add(taskToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Sorry should have put in place this line of code:  var taskToUpdate = $org.context.Task.attachOrGet({ Id:task.TaskId});